# Like "time-inhomogeneous," but for space

Tags: terminology

I'm talking about a random walk that is homogeneous in time but not in space--is there a term for this? I've searched for "space-inhomogeneous" but nothing came up.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just went with "position-(in)dependent," and people seemed to know what I meant.

Comment: I mean, I needed a term and this is the best term I could find, which seems like an answer to me. Can you clarify what counts as an answer, if this doesn't cut it?